# pandas dataframe to numpy array without the annoying dtype="blah blah"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I selected several rows of the first column and used both .values and as_matrix() to convert it to numpy array.

```
x1 = df.iloc[[1,3,4,64,34], 0]
```

The dimension of the each element in the dataframe is a (3, 3, 5) numpy array. I would like to output a (5, 3, 3, 5) numpy array from the dataframe. However when I use .values, i get a (5, ) shape array with a dtype =unit8 at the end of each element. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: must have been by accident

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[np.ones((3, 3, 5))] * 5))

A = np.array([a.tolist() for a in df.iloc[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 0]])

print(A.shape)

(5, 3, 3, 5)
```